# How do I pass this.data through to other components with React and Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, client-server, axios

I am running a client and server setup (react and axios api calls) And I would like to understand how to access the returned data from my child components within the React Framework.  I have the connection working to the  http server, however i lack the foundational knowledge of working with this.state or props.

here is effectively my app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import ChildComponent from "./components/childComponent"

class App extends Component {
 state = {
  data: [],
  intervalIsSet : false
};

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getDataFromDb();
    if (!this.state.intervalIsSet) {
      let interval = setInterval(this.getDataFromDb, 10000);
      this.setState({ intervalIsSet: interval });
    }
  }

  getDataFromDb = () => {
    fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/getData")
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(res => this.setState({ data: res.data }));
  };

 render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
       <div>
         <childComponent />
       </div>

  );
};
}

export default App;
```

and here is the child component.  --> my intention is to simply access (or print out) my returned data from the server from within the child component.

import React, { Component } from 'react';

```
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
            {this.props.data}
      );
    }
  }

  export default ChildComponent;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you `uppercase` the first letter of `ChildComponent`. If you want to pass data you should add that object as an attribute to the `component`, and then access it throught `this.props`. Also you need to render a single top element, and if you don't need `div` or any other html element, you can wrap it with `React.Fragment`.

Regarding to `data`, if its an array you can simply `map` through it and return data you want to see, if you want the entire object to show as a string, you can use `JSON.stringify()`. And if that's an `object` you can show only data you want.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  //...
  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent data={data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

//for array, ex: data = ["first","name"];
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {this.props.data.map(item => 
          <p>{item}</p>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

//for object, ex: data = {id: 1, name: 'John'};
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {data} = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p>{data.id}</p>
        <p>{data.name}</p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

//for single value (string, int, etc), ex: data = "my name";
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <p>{this.props.data}</p>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

//to show object as a string (could be any object mentioned before)
class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {JSON.stringify(this.props.data)}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass down the `data` array as the `data` prop to the child component. Make sure you also uppercase the first character in the component name, or it won't work properly.

A component needs to render a single top level element, so you could e.g. render a `div` with the JSON stringified `data` prop inside of it in the child component.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <ChildComponent data={data} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>{JSON.stringify(this.props.data)}</div>;
  }
}
```